# Automatically export data from Salesforce

Tags: data-loader, xml, cli

I created a script to automatically extract data from Data Loader.

I tried testing the SOQL in the dev console and it's showing the correct data, but when I used it in XML file the process is extracting the data but it's showing as blank in the currency column.

Query used in dev console:

```
Select Name ,convertCurrency(Cost__c) FROM Custom__c
```

Query used in XML:

```
Select Name ,convertCurrency(Cost__c) FROM Custom__c
```

Also, if you have any other way to extract the data using my home currency, rather than showing the records' actual currency.

My end goal here is to automatically extract data from Salesforce in to a csv file.

Thank you

Comment: Do you use the same user for both?

Comment: Yes, as per SF Support convertCurrency() function is not working in data loader. I'm trying to look for workaround

Comment: You can use Salesforce CLI and run the command `force:data:soql:query -r csv` instead of using Data Loader.

Comment: Can you try export functionality using the dataloader.io ? It should give converted amounts after export.